# Will Blender support design and dimensioning machine drawings?

Tags: edit-mode

I am starting a search for software that can support mechanical design.  The CAD programs I have looked at tend to have arcane command language interfaces that make the job of design as much a programming exercise as a creativity tool.

My question is: "Will Blender support design and dimensioning machine drawings?"

If so, where do I go to learn more?

Comment: No, hard to say without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve, but unfortunately I don't think Blender is adequate for that sort of work. In fact Blender is particularly unsuited for any CAD-like precision modelling work, and is one of its weakest points. Maybe look into [LibreCAD](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) or perhaps [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) is more suited for manufacturing?

Answer (score 2):

While blender is more adapted to creative modeling than technical or precision modeling you can create mechanical models and use them to create good looking blueprints.

In [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb1U7g4JFbA), the measrueit addon (included with 2.78 or can be [manually installed](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/measureit) on older versions) is used to create the measurement lines. The lines and annotations don't show in a normal render, but the addon provides a way to create a render with measurements.

[image: measureit blueprint]

[Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/introduction.html) can also be used to create outlines for blueprints. [This blendertuts tutorial](http://blendtuts.com/tutorials-list/freestyleblueprinteffect) explains how to define solid and [dashed linestyles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_style/strokes.html#dashed-line) to get a hidden edge blueprint result. It is also possible to get more of a hand sketched result.

[image: blendtuts result]

The CGCookie archives also [has an old tutorial](https://cgcookie.com/archive/creating-a-cool-blueprint/) that manually creates text objects and lines to get the following blueprint.

[image: blendercookie blueprint]